# GetElementsByTagName only returning first node in array

Tags: php

I am trying to get each element in the array using `getElementsByTagName`

```
$xmlString = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<order>
<line-items type="array">
<line-item>
<title>Title 1</title>
</line-item>
<line-item>
<title>Title 2</title>
</line-item>
</line-items>
    </order>';
```

But have only been able to get the first result (Title 1).

```
$dom = new DomDocument();
$dom->loadXML($xmlString);
$order = $dom->getElementsByTagName('line-items');

foreach($order as $get){
echo $dom->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->textContent;
}
```

How do I ensure I loop over `line-items` and get every possible iteration of `title` in every `line-item` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to iterate through all the 'line-item' elements and get the title, not 'line-items' as it just appeared once. So the modified code might look like below :

```
$order = $dom->getElementsByTagName('line-item');
foreach($order as $get){
   //echo $dom->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->textContent;
   //echo $order->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->textContent;

     echo $get->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->textContent;
}
```

That should solve the issue.

Comment: This is outputting `Title 1` `Title 1`, and is outputting first node twice not getting `Title 2`

Comment: `Title 2` is in `$dom->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(1)->textContent;` is why

Comment: Nope... now I am getting `Fatal error: Call to undefined method DOMNodeList::getElementsByTagName() in C:\wamp64\www\xml\test.php on line 28` Line 28 being `echo $order->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->textContent;` hmm..

Comment: hmm, plz check now

Comment: `Title 1` `Title 2` thank you! I was having a difficult time with this and was kind of looking wrong way, thanks again

Comment: Welcome Brian.. and glad that it helped :)